# Best solution for multithreading lock list in the existing code?

Tags: c#, multithreading, list

I have a project in asp.net. 
I have a class `FieldInfo` which contain a `List<ValueInfo>`.
`List<ValueInfo>` was used in many places. But sometimes, I have to changed the list (clear items and add items again), so I had a problem with multithreaded because someone are reading list, someone clear the list.
Code to read `List<ValueInfo>` was used in many places, code to write code only in a place.
I want to ask that: is there a solution for me to ensure threadsafe read/write and I don't have to change anything for "reading `List<ValueInfo>`"(if I change,I have to change a lot of code)?

`FieldInfo` definition:

```
class FieldInfo
{
    public List<ValueInfo> listValueInfo { get; set; }
}
```

Code to write list:

```
listValueInfo.clear();
listValueInfo.add(valueInfoObject);
```

Code to read list (in many files, many places):

```
foreach(ValueInfo valueinfo in listValueInfo)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a look at the System.Collections.Concurrent namespace:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

This contains thread-safe collections that you can use instead of a List (for example a ConcurrentBag. Or just put a lock around the thread unsafe operations like this. Just make sure the lock object is the same for all threads (or use the collection itself as the lock object)

```
 private object lockObject = new object();

//Write 
lock(_lockObject)
 {
    listValueInfo.clear(); 
    listValueInfo.add(valueInfoObject);
}
//Read
lock(_lockObject)
{

   foreach(ValueInfo valueinfo in listValueInfo)
   {

   }
}
```

Comment: While the concurrent collections are useful, none has all the semantics of `List<T>`. None of them has a `Clear` method, for example.

Comment: Concurrent collections is in .net 4.0 and 4.5.My project was in 3.5. It means I don't have a choice, I have to change code to read list as Jeroen1984 suggested?

Comment: @user3796752 Ok, maybe you should mention that in your question (or upgrade to 4.5 ;-)). How about simply lock your operations that should be atomic, does that help you?

Comment: `BlockingCollection<T>` implements `ICollection`. `ICollection` has a `Clear` method. It is probably implemented explicitly. Try casting to `ICollection` before clearing. `IList` implements the same interface but it is implicit.

Comment: @Gusdor `ICollection<T>` has Clear. `ICollection` does not. `BlockingCollection<T>` implements `ICollection`, but not `ICollection<T>`.

Comment: @Jeroen1984 your code can help me. If I can not find a better solution, I will follow your solution. I have to change a lot of code if I follow your solution. So I am expecting a better solution which I only change less code. Thank you very much.

Comment: @user3796752  If you just put the lock around the Clear() and Add() functions (which are in one single place you said), you already made sure that those two operations are called without another thread reading the collection in the meanwhile.. Maybe that's already enough for you. Don't think you can accomplish this without changing your code. You can also wrap your List in a class that manages the thead-safety, and for example call GetItemsThreadSafe() on that class, and let the GetItemsThreadSafe() do the locking. Then you already have the thread-safety logic for that collection in one place.